# How to install LAMP in Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash

Tags: lamp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to install LAMP in Ubuntu. I have installed Apache. 
After the command `sudo ufw allow in "Apache Full"` it shows 
"unable to resolve host". How can I solve this?

Comment: see https://blog.netnerds.net/2016/04/active-directory-and-php-on-apache-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/

Answer (score 7):

To `resolve`*`the host`* just add *`it`* to `/etc/hosts`, like at the example:

[image: Resolve Host]

For more details read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/811113/566421).

---

According to the @Rinzwind's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808770/how-to-install-lamp-in-windows-10-ubuntu-bash/808852#comment1221952_808770), I think, port 80/443 must be opened in the Windows firewall. [**Here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AcqibSJ8ng) is a video instruction about it.

---

If you have a router and you want your web server to be accessible from outside, don’t forget to add some port forwarding. Something like that:

[image: Port Forwarding]

---

I will leave here and these few tips about [UFW](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) configuration on native Ubuntu:

To allow external access to Apache through UFW, you need to use:

```
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
```

To enable `tcp` protocol only use:

```
sudo ufw allow http/tcp
sudo ufw allow https/tcp
```

You can use and the port number directly:

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```

For some services (like "SSH" or "Webnin", which by default uses web interface at port 10000) you can add little security by using of `limit` rule instead of `allow`. This will limit the number of login attempts per certain time for these ports:

```
sudo ufw limit ssh/tcp
sudo ufw limit 10000/tcp
```

Just in case you can reload the "rules table":

```
sudo ufw reload
```

Comment: Sorry but he asked about bash in WINDOWS. How do you see this answering 1. that there is no GUI in windows (so you also need an X-server). and 2. that you need windows related software (like `ktpass`).

Answer (score 2):

### Get updates

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

### Install LAMP

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mariadb-server php5-mysql php5-cli php5-gd
```

### Change port

if Windows is using 80 already

```
vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

Change 80 to 8080

### Start services

```
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service mysql start
```

### Clean urls

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Then:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

### Create database

```
mysql -uroot -proot -e 'create database your-db-name;
```

### Install Composer

- https://getcomposer.org/download/

Make it global

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```